# How to output the coins that were repeated

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked to create an array that holds 5 users inputted coins (penny, nickel, dime, or quarter). Once the user typed in any of his 5 coin amounts in decimal form, I am supposed to output the coins that they inputted (in decimal form), along with the largest amount coin that they inputted (greatest value coin can go as high as a quarter) and the smallest amount coin inputted (smallest value coin can go as low as a penny). **I am also supposed to output which coins were repeated but I don't have a clue how to do that.** Since the user is inputting 5 coins, that means at least one coin will be used more than once (assuming I am asking the user for only those 4 coins). Any suggestions? Example would be: "the coins repeated are: quarter:2, dime:5 .etc

P.S. I apologize in advance for my sloppy coding, I'm sure there are simpler ways to do this, first time learning.

```
enter code here

package HwMoney;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Coins2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

        double coin[]=new double[5];
        int[] num={1,2,3,4,5};

        System.out.println("enter coin values");
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 coins values in decimal format,");
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
        System.out.print("coin " + num[i] +":\t");
            coin[i] = kb.nextDouble();

        }

        System.out.println("your coins that you put in are: ");
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
        System.out.print(coin[i]+"\t");


        }

        System.out.println();
        Arrays.sort(coin);

        double max = coin[4];
        if(max == .25)
        System.out.println("Your greatest coin is: quarter");
        else if(max == .10)
        System.out.println("Your greatest coin is: dime");
        else if(max == .05)
        System.out.println("Your greatest coin is: nickle");
        else if(max == .01)
        System.out.println("Yout greatest coin is: penny");
        else 
        System.out.println("try again you gave me the wrong numbers");


        double min = coin[0];
        if(min == .25)
        System.out.println("Your smallest coin is: quarter");
        else if(min == .10)
        System.out.println("Your smallest coin is: dime");
        else if(min == .05)
        System.out.println("Your smallest coin is: nickle");
        else if(min == .01)
        System.out.println("Your smallest coin is: penny");

}
/*enter coin values
Enter the 5 coins values in decimal format,
coin 1: .05
coin 2: .10
coin 3: .25
coin 4: .01
coin 5: .10
your coins that you put in are: 
0.05    0.1 0.25    0.01    0.1 
Your greatest coin is: quarter
Your smallest coin is: penny

*/
```

}

Comment: Okay...so what is the question you're *actually* asking?  I get the problem description, but I don't see a question from you.

Comment: @Hamster I have posted my answer, it takes care of max, min and duplicates with counts... hope it will also be helpful to you, in case of an issue please comment. (I hv used my mobile to post an answer and have tried best to have it error free :), but in case of an issue do tell )..http://stackoverflow.com/a/42103844/504133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop around and compare to the next element

```
    double lastVal = -1.0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if (coin[i] == coin [i+1] && lastVal != coin[i]) {  // prevent reading same value
            lastVal = coin[i];
            if(coin[i] == .25) 
                System.out.println("quarter is repeated");
            if(coin[i] == .10) 
                System.out.println("dime is repeated");
            // etc

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, absolutely fabulous. Literally burst into tears after seeing this code. I spent way too many hours looking through my textbook and notes. Thankyou **so** much

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is just having an accumulator for each coin. For example, when the first coin input is 0.10, you would add 1 to the dime accumulator.

Example:

```
    // define accumulator

    int num_dimes = 0;
    System.out.println("your coins that you put in are: ");
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
    System.out.print(coin[i]+"\t");
       if (coin[i] = 0.10)
           num_dimes = num_dimes + 1; //I think you can say num_dimes += 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson 1: Arrays are for experts. Everyone else, use Collections.

In this case, a `Map` is your friend:

```
TreeMap<Double, Integer> coins = new TreeMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    double coin = kb.nextDouble();
    // check input is valid if you like
    coins.merge(coin, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
}

System.out.println("You have:");
coins.forEach((c, n) -> System.out.println(n + " of " + c));

System.out.println("Your greatest coin is " + coins.lastKey());
System.out.println("Your least coin is " + coins.firstKey());
```

Using a TreeMap makes your job even easier than a HashMap would, because it iterates in key order which you want for your output, and gives you highest and lowest keys for free.

If you submit this code as your homework, make sure you understand it!

Comment: Thank you very much! The code definitely looks a lot more refurbished! Although I haven't learned TreeMap yet, I will definitely look into it! I always enjoy new material! Thank you. I consider myself a noob XD.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a `Set` or a `Map` for this. You can use `Map` If your requirement is ( or may be tomorrow may be) to have the number of each coins (assuming user can choose more than 2 coins , like all 5 coins same or 3 coins same.

You would need to import `java.util.HashMap`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
   double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

   Map < Double, Integer > countMap = new HashMap < >();
   Map <Double,String > valueNameMap = new HashMap < > ();
    // mapping penny, nickel, dime, or quarter
    valueNameMap.put (0.01, "penny");
    valueNameMap.put (0.05, "nickel");
    valueNameMap.put (0.10, "dime");
    valueNameMap.put (0.25, "quater");

    System.out.println("enter coin values");
    System.out.println("Enter the 5 coins values in decimal   ");

  for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
    System.out.print("coin " + (i + 1) +":\t");
        double input = kb.nextDouble();
       if( input < min ){min = input};
       if( input > max ){max = input};
       Integer count = countMap.get(input);
       if(count != null ){
           //input is duplicate
           countMap.put(input,count+1);
       }else {
           countMap.put(input,0);
      }
   }
    if(valueName.get(max) ! = null ){
           System.out.println("Your greatest coin is: "+valueNameMap.get(max));
     }else {  
         System.out.println(" wrong greatest coin inputted ");
    }
    if(valueName.get(min) ! = null ){
           System.out.println("Your smallest coin is: "+valueNameMap.get(min));
     }else {  
         System.out.println(" wrong minimum coin inputted ");
    }

  for(Double coin : countMap.keySet()){
       Integer count = countMap.get(coin);
      if (count ! = null && count > 1) {
          System.out.println(" we have a duplicate coin :" + valueNameMap.get(coin) +" its entered " + count + " times " );
     }
  }
}
```